# Augmentation ideal of the cohomology of an elemntary abelian 2-group

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let V be an elemntary abelian 2-group and $R=H^{*}V$ its cohomology.
What is the Augmentation ideal of R and what is the quotient of R by its augmentation ideal ?

Comment: Please give a specific reference. My guess would be that the augmentation ideal is the reduced cohomology (and the quotient is just $\mathbb{Z}$).